# using the datediff function and avg function in the same statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am VERY new to any language. In sql, I'm trying to find the avg of data using the datediff function to compute the age.  I know the ages, but I simply have no clue as how to write the statement.

when I run this statement, I get the information I'm looking for. However, I also need to use the datediff function to compute the age from the DOB. This is where I get lost.  Here is what I have, and I get an error when I run it.

```
 select firstname,lastname, dob
  SELECT DATEDIFF(day,'1970-01-01','1978-05-27') AS DiffDate
  where occupationId = 164 and gender = 'M';
```

Again, I new to this and have researched for and answer and to get understanding. I need help.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? Because MySQL only has two parameters in `DATEDIFF` i.e. `DATEDIFF('1970-01-01', '1978-05-27')` whereas SQL Server has three parameters, the third being the _date interval_ which is what you have used.

Comment: I'm using SQL Pro Server

Comment: I mean what is the database you are using? MySQL Server, Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle? SQL Pro Server is a tool for working on databases I believe which is not what I was asking. Also recommend you include the error message in your question that you are receiving.

Comment: Sorry...MySQL server

Comment: Okay. Will get the tag changes reverted.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few issues with your SQL query.

1. MySQL `DATEDIFF` does not have an *interval* parameter i.e. `day`. It only takes two datetime parameters. During your research, you must've come across SQL Server documentation.
2. Use `TIMESTAMPDIFF` instead (which takes an *interval*) like so `TIMESTAMPDIFF(year, dob, CURDATE()) AS currentage` which gets you their current age.
3. No `FROM` clause and table is specified, so where are you getting `firstname, lastname, dob, occupationId` and `gender` from?
4. You do not need a sub select query to calculate the age.

The revised query for you (you'll need to specify the table name where you're getting your data from):

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, dob, TIMESTAMPDIFF(year, dob, CURDATE()) AS currentage 
FROM tableName 
WHERE occupationId = 164 and gender = 'M';
```

`

Comment: Thank you sooooo very much.  I have adjusted the code to this           SELECT  avg(age), TIMESTAMPDIFF(year, dob, CURDATE()) AS currentage FROM users WHERE occupationId = 164 and gender = 'M';  I removed the firstname, lastname.  It now runs given me the average I need.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to do...Select the average age for all male, college/university professors. Use the datediff  function to compute age from DOB.

Comment: Recommend reviewing MySQL's [AVG](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg) function to get you the average of all ages.